# Python: Use of threading for fitness evaluation in Genetic Algorithms

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm curious if threading is the right approach for my use case. I'm working on a genetic algorithm, which needs to evaluate the fitness of genes 1...n. The evaluation of each is independent of others for the most part. Yet, each gene will be passed through the same function, `eval(gene`.

My intention is that once all genes have been evaluated, I will sort by fitness, and only retain top x.

From this [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-python-set-1/), it seems that I should be able to do the following, where the specifics of `eval` are out of scope for this question, but suppose each function call updates a common dictionary of form, `{gene : fitness}`:

```py
for gene in gene_pool:
   thread_i = threading.Thread(target=eval(gene), name=f"fitness gene{i}")
   thread_i.start()

for i in range(len(genes)):
   thread_i.join()
```

In the tutorial, I don't see the function actually invoking the function `eval()`, but rather just referencing its name, `eval`. I'm not sure if this will problematic for my use case.

My first question is: Is this the right approach? Should I consider a different approach to threading?

I don't believe that I will need to account for race conditions or locks because, while every thread will update the same dictionary, the keys and values will be independent.

And my last question: Does multiprocessing generally a better bet? It seems that it's a bit higher level, which might be ideal for someone new to parallelization.

Comment: Looks like the example you link to just prints stuff. Having multiple threads try to write to the same object might be asking for trouble. `asyncio.gather()` might be a better way. Does the evaulation actually take a long time, or are you just experimenting?

Comment: The evaluation will take appr half a second per instance (on local machine), so being able to parallelize will sharply reduce overall computation time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, **threading** is constrained by the GIL, so that it is very limited performance-wise. In case of IO-bound code (reading/writing files, requests on the network, ...) **async** is the way to go.
But from what you explain, your code is rather CPU-bound (computing many things). Then if you want your code to go fast then you need to circumvent the Python GIL. There is two main ways :

- **multiprocessing** (having multiple different Python processes in parallel)
- or calling code written in lower-level languages (Cython, C, ...), typically wrapped in a nice library

If you want something simple, stick to [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) : at the start create a pool whose size is the number of competing genes (N), then at each iteration submit to the pool N new tasks to it and wait for their results (the `pool.map` function), repeat as many times as you want.
I think it is the simplest way to get a full parallelization, which should give you decent speed.

Comment: One quick question, the target environment will be an AWS EC2 instance. Given this, are there any OS peculiarities that I will need to navigate? (OS most likely Linux.) Python, being a higher level language, tends to abstract most of these concerns away, so I anticipate that it will be a non-issue.

Comment: @jbuddy_13 depending on the type of instance you use, you will have a varying number of threads. Typically, most of the cheaper types have few **vCPU** which directly limits the number of different threads/cores that you are permitted to run simultaneously. In these cases, you won't get a huge speedup even from **multiprocessing** because it will be hardware-limited. But on beefier instances, you can have dozens of vCPU, which can result in a huge speedup.

Comment: Excellent! As a funded work project, I expect a 32 core instance. By default, the GA is configured to host 18 genes (hyper parameter.) Sounds like this is a feasible solution, thanks :)